# Postman shows "Unknown authentication strategy \"local\"" when Im not even defining the passport strategy

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, passport.js

I am have been struggling with this problem for days now. I change my code every now and then but nothing works so this time i deleted my code for passport.use (i couldn't use it in the right way i don't know how to do it) but left the router.post() to see if i get any errors and yes the same error that appeared while i have the passport config still shows so i guess it's from here the problem anyone can hep and tell me why im getting this error with and without the passport config (btw i use postgresql for database).

```
              router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
                    failureRedirect: '/users/login',


                   },console.log("tessst"),),
                    function(req, res) {
                   console.log('Authentication successful');
                   res.redirect('/login');
                         });
```

is the problem with this part? what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define and use a passport strategy with the name 'local' first. Only then you can use the strategy with the same name.

There is a passport strategy named [passport-local](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/) which you can use.